# Elasticsearch after reverse nested problem

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregate

after using reverse nesting in nested aggregation in Elasticsearch, the previous aggregation is not taken into account. For example: I have 2 objects in nested, after showing them separately with the aggregation, I use reverse nested to display the root element, and it shows it in the correct form.But the other aggregation that comes after reverse nested shows the root according to all its objects, not according to the previous 2 objects.

```
    "aggs": {
        "feedback_terms": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "id",
                "size": 10712
            },
            "aggs": {
                "service_nested": {
                    "nested": {
                        "path": "feedback_rate"
                    },
                    "aggs": {
                        "service_terms": {
                            "terms": {
                                "field": "feedback_rate.service.name.keyword",
                                "size": 200,
                                "order": {
                                    "_key": "asc"
                                }
                            },
                            "aggs": {
                                "branch_reverse": {
                                    "reverse_nested": {},
                                    "aggs": {
                                        "branch_terms": {
                                            "terms": {
                                                "field": "branch.name.keyword",
                                                "size": 100,
                                                "order": {
                                                    "_key": "asc"
                                                }
                                            },
                                            "aggs": {
                                                "rate_nested": {
                                                    "nested": {
                                                        "path": "feedback_rate"
                                                    },
                                                    "aggs": {
                                                        "rate_terms": {
                                                            "terms": {
                                                                "field": "feedback_rate.rate_option",
                                                                "script": {
                                                                    "params": {
                                                                        "rateOption": {
                                                                            "1": "Excellent",
                                                                            "2": "Good",
                                                                            "3": "Neutral",
                                                                            "4": "Bad",
                                                                            "5": "Unacceptable"
                                                                        }
                                                                    },
                                                                    "source": "def rate =params.rateOption; def value = doc['feedback_rate.rate_option'].value.toString(); return rate.containsKey(value) ? rate[value] : value"
                                                                },
                                                                "value_type": "string"
                                                            },
                                                            "aggs": {
                                                                "rate_count_metric": {
                                                                    "value_count": {
                                                                        "field": "feedback_rate.rate_option"
                                                                    }
                                                                },
                                                                "feedback_count_reverse": {
                                                                    "reverse_nested": {},
                                                                    "aggs": {
                                                                        "feedback_count_metric": {
                                                                            "value_count": {
                                                                                "field": "id"
                                                                            }
                                                                        }
                                                                    }
                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

It gives an output as follows

```
    "aggregations": {
        "feedback_terms": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key": 218455,
                    "doc_count": 1,
                    "service_nested": {
                        "doc_count": 4,
                        "service_terms": {
                            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                            "buckets": [
                                {
                                    "key": " Czytelność oznakowania budynku",
                                    "doc_count": 1,
                                    "branch_reverse": {
                                        "doc_count": 1,
                                        "branch_terms": {
                                            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                                            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                                            "buckets": [
                                                {
                                                    "key": "Sąd Rejonowy Praga Północ",
                                                    "doc_count": 1,
                                                    "rate_nested": {
                                                        "doc_count": 4,
                                                        "rate_terms": {
                                                            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                                                            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                                                            "buckets": [
                                                                {
                                                                    "key": "Excellent",
                                                                    "doc_count": 2,
                                                                    "rate_count_metric": {
                                                                        "value": 2
                                                                    },
                                                                    "feedback_count_reverse": {
                                                                        "doc_count": 1,
                                                                        "feedback_count_metric": {
                                                                            "value": 1
                                                                        }
                                                                    }
                                                                },
                                                                {
                                                                    "key": "Unacceptable",
                                                                    "doc_count": 2,
                                                                    "rate_count_metric": {
                                                                        "value": 2
                                                                    },
                                                                    "feedback_count_reverse": {
                                                                        "doc_count": 1,
                                                                        "feedback_count_metric": {
                                                                            "value": 1
                                                                        }
                                                                    }
                                                                }
                                                            ]
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "key": "Sprawność obsługi",
                                    "doc_count": 1,
                                    "branch_reverse": {
                                        "doc_count": 1,
                                        "branch_terms": {
                                            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                                            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                                            "buckets": [
                                                {
                                                    "key": "Sąd Rejonowy Praga Północ",
                                                    "doc_count": 1,
                                                    "rate_nested": {
                                                        "doc_count": 4,
                                                        "rate_terms": {
                                                            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                                                            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                                                            "buckets": [
                                                                {
                                                                    "key": "Excellent",
                                                                    "doc_count": 2,
                                                                    "rate_count_metric": {
                                                                        "value": 2
                                                                    },
                                                                    "feedback_count_reverse": {
                                                                        "doc_count": 1,
                                                                        "feedback_count_metric": {
                                                                            "value": 1
                                                                        }
                                                                    }
                                                                },
                                                                {
                                                                    "key": "Unacceptable",
                                                                    "doc_count": 2,
                                                                    "rate_count_metric": {
                                                                        "value": 2
                                                                    },
                                                                    "feedback_count_reverse": {
                                                                        "doc_count": 1,
                                                                        "feedback_count_metric": {
                                                                            "value": 1
                                                                        }
                                                                    }
                                                                }
                                                            ]
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

But this is the format I was expecting.

```
    "aggregations": {
        "feedback_terms": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key": 218455,
                    "doc_count": 1,
                    "service_nested": {
                        "doc_count": 4,
                        "service_terms": {
                            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                            "buckets": [
                                {
                                    "key": " Czytelność oznakowania budynku",
                                    "doc_count": 1,
                                    "branch_reverse": {
                                        "doc_count": 1,
                                        "branch_terms": {
                                            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                                            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                                            "buckets": [
                                                {
                                                    "key": "Sąd Rejonowy Praga Północ",
                                                    "doc_count": 1,
                                                    "rate_nested": {
                                                        "doc_count": 4,
                                                        "rate_terms": {
                                                            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                                                            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                                                            "buckets": [
                                                                {
                                                                    "key": "Excellent",
                                                                    "doc_count": 1,
                                                                    "rate_count_metric": {
                                                                        "value": 1
                                                                    },
                                                                    "feedback_count_reverse": {
                                                                        "doc_count": 1,
                                                                        "feedback_count_metric": {
                                                                            "value": 1
                                                                        }
                                                                    }
                                                                }
                                                            ]
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "key": "Sprawność obsługi",
                                    "doc_count": 1,
                                    "branch_reverse": {
                                        "doc_count": 1,
                                        "branch_terms": {
                                            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                                            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                                            "buckets": [
                                                {
                                                    "key": "Sąd Rejonowy Praga Północ",
                                                    "doc_count": 1,
                                                    "rate_nested": {
                                                        "doc_count": 4,
                                                        "rate_terms": {
                                                            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                                                            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                                                            "buckets": [
                                                                {
                                                                    "key": "Unacceptable",
                                                                    "doc_count": 1,
                                                                    "rate_count_metric": {
                                                                        "value": 1
                                                                    },
                                                                    "feedback_count_reverse": {
                                                                        "doc_count": 1,
                                                                        "feedback_count_metric": {
                                                                            "value": 1
                                                                        }
                                                                    }
                                                                }
                                                            ]
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```